# AngularJS: $watch other service in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an service, and want to watch the data of an other service (so an event is triggered, when the data is changed).

```
// Gets data from an json file and saves it in this.data
myService.service('myService', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.data = {}; // This will be returned by $watch

    this.loadData = function( ){
        $http.get('http://localhost/data.json').
            success(function(json, status, headers, config) {
                this.data = json; // This wont be returned by $watch
            });
    }
}]);
```

Now, is some different services, I call the load function and have a $watch event:

```
// Load data
myService.loadData( );

// $watch attempt #1
$rootScope.$watch('myService.data', function(data){
    console.log(myService.data);
}, true);

// $watch attempt #2
$rootScope.$watch(function(){
    return myService.data;
}, function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal);
});
```

Both $watch attempts will show me in my Firebug-Console: {} (from this.data = {};)
But this.data = json; wont be displayed.

What did I do wrong? Is there a way do get an event when the data is changed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `data` to wrong object because the context (`this`) is going to be different inside `success` callback. Simple fix is to referent service context with some variable, like `var self = this`:

```
this.loadData = function() {
    var self = this;
    $http.get('http://localhost/data.json').
        success(function(json, status, headers, config) {
            self.data = json;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect. Ill use that, since its seems very easy.

Comment: Yes, this one is the simplest and also a little more performant. But the one with bind has also advantages that it's a little nicer, no need of one more variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt was correct but you have a problem with the service:

The keyword `this` lost it's context inside the asynchronous callback.

```
this.loadData = function( ){
    $http.get('http://localhost/data.json').
        success(function(json, status, headers, config) {
            // the keyword this lost it's context here
        });
}
```

You can use `angular.bind` to preserve the right context:

```
this.loadData = function( ){
    $http.get('http://localhost/data.json').
        success(angular.bind(this, function(json, status, headers, config) {
            this.data = json;
        }));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I tested both answers, and both works fine!